# Add an EventHandler for MouseEnter and MouseLeave in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I am generating a list of Panels, Labels and PicutreBoxes based on lines in a file.
I am using to read the lines and output the content a foreach loop.

Everything works except the EventHandler for MouseEnter and MouseLeave.
I want change the Background Color of the Panels, which are created programmatically, when the mouse moves over each label separately.

````
public void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length;
            int movePointEntry = 50; // Y-Starting Point of entry-list
            int movePanelPosition = 60; // Y-Starting point of panel creation
            int moveSeparatorLine = 79; // Y-Starting point of panel splitter-line creation
            int scoregreen; // Needed for drawing green score boxes
            int scoregrey; // Needed for drawing grey score boxes

            labelQuickStat.Text = "Database / Index";


            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Reverse())
            {
                int i = 0;
                List<string> EntrySplit = new List<string>();
                EntrySplit = line.Split('|').ToList();

                ////////////////////////////////////
                // Column / Panel
                ////////////////////////////////////
                Panel[] PanelMouseOver = new Panel[lineCount];
                PanelMouseOver[i] = new Panel();

                PanelMouseOver[i].Name = "PanelMouseOver" + i;
                PanelMouseOver[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 18);
                PanelMouseOver[i].Location = new Point(30, movePanelPosition);
                PanelMouseOver[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                PanelMouseOver[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31);
                PanelMouseOver[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(PanelMouseOver_Enter);
                PanelMouseOver[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(PanelMouseOver_Leave);

                panelDatabaseFill.Controls.Add(PanelMouseOver[i]);

// --> and more ```
````

The lines I struggle with are those:

```
                PanelMouseOver[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(PanelMouseOver_Enter);
                PanelMouseOver[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(PanelMouseOver_Leave);
```

````
    void PanelMouseOver_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ???
    }

    void PanelMouseOver_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ???
    }```
````

And here comes my issue. I thought
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31);
would be the solution, but not the programmatically generated panels changes the color, but the background of the whole program. I really don't get it.

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: `if(sender is Panel panel) panel.BackgroundColor=Colors.Blue;`

Comment: omg, this works instantly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of refering to "this" (which is your program) you should refer to the "sender". For that cast the sender to Panel into a new variable and set that to the new color.

```
Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31);
```